# Basemap loading very slow in QGIS

Tags: qgis, basemap

I am trying to load OSM Standard basemap using quickmapservicces plugin in QGIS. It used to work perfectly in my previous and other laptops. I recently bought a new one. Its a higher performance machine but the basemap is super slow on here. The internet is working fine. Everything is working properly except for the basemap. I have tried clearing all the temp files but no good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you use xyz tiles instead? You can add many source with: https://github.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/blob/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

Comment: I will look into this. If it works it would be a great help. Thanks a lot..

Comment: make sure the project CRS is 3857

Comment: Still no help. I have tried using xyz tiles and the CRS is 3857 as well.

Comment: It is consuming too much data

Comment: I havent found anyone else facing similar issue.